# How to do async destruction of object and immediately assign a new one

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
class A {
    A() {
    //initiate t1 and t2 here and put work for them to do
    }
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t1;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t2;
}
```

Now suppose I do the following:

```
A a = A();
a = A();
```

In the first line, `a` will be an `A` object which holds some threads that are running. When the second line runs, it deletes the old `A` object to create a new one. This deletion does not respect the thread's that are running.

Now, suppose I do the following modification:

```
class A {
    A() {
    //initiate t1 and t2 here and put work for them to do
    }
    ~A() {
    //send signal to t1 for it to stop 
    //send signal to t2 for it to stop
    //wait for threads to stop
        t1.join();
        t2.join(); 
    }
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t1;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t2;
}
```

This way, when I run

```
A a = A();
a = A();
```

the threads will stop gracefully before their pointers `t1` and `t2` get destructed, because the destructor of the class is called before the destructor of its members.

However, there's still a problem.

When the first line is executed, `A a = A();`, a `A` class is created and the threads start to run. When the second line arrives, `a = A();`, I **think** that the destructor of `a` gets called and we have to wait for all threads to get destructed (which could take time), and only then, a new `A` is assigned. This is not good since our code is blocked until all threads are finish and only then a new `A` is assigned.

**So, is there a way to destruct an object in an async way and immediately assign a new one?**

I thought about calling the destructor using std::async but I found out that I shouldn't call destructors manually because their second call (when the object gets out of scope) will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: why not just keep the threads, and assign new work to them when a new `A` is created ?

Comment: `a = A();` does not **delete** the object; it **destroys** it. The two are vastly different.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that the destructor of a gets called and we have to wait for all threads to get destructed (which could take time), and only then, a new A is assigned.

Yes, but the new temporary `A` already exists and so work started in constructor would progress.

The move assignment would indeed be finished only once first instance is destroyed.

So unless you want to continue next code, provided snippet is correct.

Else `swap` might be a solution to delay the destruction of first instance.

Comment: You mean `A a = A(); A b = A(); std::swap(a,b);` then I simply don't care about `b` anymore? It'll still have to be destructed in the future and it'll block whatever I'm doing, wouldn't it?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: Yes, you **delay** `b`'s destruction at end of scope, instead of the assignation. you might signal `b` to stop before `swap`

Comment: But isn't there a way to destruct `b` assynchronally so I never have to wait for my threads to stop?

Comment: You might `detach` them instead of `join`, but you have to guaranty they finish before application.

Comment: I cannot detach them because the work they do is on A itself, so if A gets destructed they'll crash the program